# How to get related to db.Model entity from datastore - what API allows it?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to read related to model entity. What API I should use?

For example:

```
class DeleteMe(db.Model):
  x = db.FloatProperty()

DeleteMe(key_name = '1').put()
```

How to read raw entity from datastore for key_name = '1'?

Answer (score 1):

To get the corresponding model that you just `put`, use `get_by_key_name`. (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get_by_key_name)

```
DeleteMe.get_by_key_name('1')
```

However, I noticed you're using the `db` package and not `ndb`. I would encourage you to use `ndb` as it has many optimizations and a more powerful API to the datastore.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/

Corresponding code for NDB might look like:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class DeleteMe(ndb.Model):
  x = ndb.FloatProperty()

DeleteMe(id='1').put()
DeleteMe.get_by_id('1')
```

Comment: ndb is not more powerful since require migration of db.models what is very costy :) This example is irrelevant to question.

Comment: it may be possible to just keep the models and use ndb anyway, depends on you setup